# CSS: Width 100% is not 100% of Screen

Tags: css

On my [sandbox site](http://quoraquora.com/index.php) there is a white bar across the top. It is contained within the body(which has the background image), and the navbars styles are

```
#topnav4 {background: #fff;  width: 100%; height: 70px;  }
```

But the bar doesn't reach the edges of the screen. Furthermore, I don`t have any margins or padding set.  does anyone know how to fix this?

**Update,** also note that the navbar is not at the very top of the screen. There is space between the top of the navbar and the top of the page. How do I get rid of this?

**Update,** I added this code but the problem is still not fixed

**#topnav4 {background: #fff; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 70px;  }**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The snippet you're looking for is:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

That will remove the default user agent "page margins" in all browsers.

Remove your `position: absolute`-based additions - that's not the optimal way to solve this problem.

Comment: @rolling stone; Just that he pointed out that position: absolute isn't the optimal way to solve the OP's problem. And at the time, he had more over any of us. Um, I just checked the times and they all say answered 18 minutes ago (except for Guffa, he came in a little later)...

Comment: @Paul Vitti: He was a scant 39 seconds before me (hover over `?? mins ago`).

Comment: @Paul Vitty no worries, its all good. I actually think you were the first to answer, but just by a little bit :)

Comment: @thirtydot true enough. +1 from me too for the most thorough answer.

Comment: I'm sorry,  @rolling stone. - I didn't know you could hover over the time to get the seconds.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to set the margin and padding of your body to 0.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a doctype on the page, so it will be rendered in Quirks Mode. This means that the browser tries to be compatible with ancient versions of the browser.

It's especially bad for IE, where it also will use a non-standard box model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

Add a doctype to the page: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: @mjmitche: Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the very first line in your HTML is the most eloquent way to follow the sound advice in this answer.

Comment: I read that I only need to use this now that html 5 is out. do you agree? <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: o.k, thanks @thirtydot, i read your comment after I posted my last comment!

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the top of your CSS file, then go and read about CSS Resets:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Here's some resources that I found helpful:

1. [Best CSS Reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset)
2. [W3 Schools (The Doctype)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp)
3. [The Box Model](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=15&ved=0CHQQFjAO&url=http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/the-box-model-for-beginners/&ei=b0sWTuXJAs73mAWD_fkn&usg=AFQjCNECEZDqKGTq9TltH9UA3fGdBziJbA&sig2=qWt9RtigmvOrXCC1jBGmjg)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it for me.

```
min-width:100%
```

Answer (score 0):

`.container {display: grid;}`

in the website and

`.container {display: block;}`

in the mobile view.

I was having the same problem and noticed that my display was set to grid and so it was adjusting to 100% of the column instead of the entire screen.